# Local reagent atom won't update when global ratom change

Tags: clojurescript, reagent

Let's say I have a component defined like this:

```
(defn test-comp
  [timespan-ratom]
  (let [[timespan-lower timespan-upper] @timespan-ratom]
    (fn []
      [:div.row (str "Testing" timespan-lower timespan-upper)])))
```

`timespan-ratom` is defined globally in the component that instantiates `test-comp` like this:

```
(def timespan-ratom (ratom nil))
```

It's instantiated like this:

```
[test-comp timespan-ratom]
```

The first time the `timespan-ratom` is used to create `test-comp` "Testing" will be printed with the correct `timespan-lower` and `timespan-upper` value. But when the `timespan-ratom` is reset (`reset!`) the values are not updated in the `test-comp` component? Why is this?

It works when I change the function to this:

```
(defn test-comp
  [timespan-ratom]
    (fn []
      [:div.row (str "Testing" (first @timespan-ratom) (second @timespan-ratom))]))
```

Now the reason why I can't simply do like this is that in my actual production code I have local ratom that is dependent on the value of the `timespan-ratom`:

```
(defn test-comp
  [timespan-ratom]
  (let [[timespan-lower timespan-upper] @timespan-ratom
        selected-time (ratom timespan-upper)]
    (fn []
      ,,,)))
```

I.e. the initial value of `selected-time` should be the `timespan-upper` value defined by the `timespan-ratom`. The `selected-time` ratom is then changed locally from the `test-comp` component.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the inner function nesting from `test-comp`:

```
(defn test-comp
  [timespan-ratom]
  (let [[timespan-lower timespan-upper] @timespan-ratom]
    [:div.row (str "Testing" timespan-lower timespan-upper)]))
```

When you use an inner function with no arguments, the component can never receive the updated ratom, so it will forever hold on to the first value it got from the ratom on the first render. Also, you don't need the inner function here, because you don't have any local state.

If you do have local state (some state that needs to be remembered over the lifetime of the component), update your component so the inner function has the same arguments as the outer function and dereference the atom in the inner function:

```
(defn test-comp
  [ratom]
  (let [x "local-state"]
    (fn [ratom]
      (let [v @ratom]
        [:div x v]))))
```

Comment: I didn't show the inner state in the simplified example but I do indeed have inner state which is affected by the `selected-time` ratom.

Comment: Then you need to add the same argument list of the outer function to the inner function. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: If the inner state which is affected by the selected-time ratom is solely derivable from that ratom it isn't really component local state though. It's just one or more values computed on each render. Please refer to https://github.com/Day8/re-frame/wiki/Creating-Reagent-Components for details.

Comment: Just want to emphasise the importance of the above link from @MichaelBorkent. There is lots of really good background material regarding reagent on the Day8 site. Understanding that material will same you LOTS of hours of learning the hard way!